# Why is EGT decreasing on a jet engine when the generators cut in (take over)?

Tags: turbofan, egt

Is the EGT decrease related to the generators cutting in or is it related to the fact that the fan is now providing enough ventilation air for the engine?

When I say cut in I mean that the engine driven generator has taken over in supplying the electrical load from the APU driven generator.

Comment: Which jet engine?

Comment: Well, the simple answer "no", since it's the rise in N2 (and therefore more air through the core) which causes the EGT to  fall.  Put it this way, if you remove the generators, the engine will start in exactly the same way.

Comment: @koyovis its the IAE V2527-A5

Comment: Please confirm that you mean begin operating / engage, which is what "cut in" typically [means](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+cut+in).

Comment: @ymb1 yes when I say cut in I mean that the engine driven generator has taken over in supplying the electrical load from the APU driven generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EGT on some engines is proportional to the engine developed power, cutting the generators reduces the needed power, thus reduces the EGT

Comment: "Cut in" [means](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+cut+in) "begin operating".